# Laravel, mismatched token error when trying to pass data via AJAX to controller

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, request, csrf

Route:

```
Route::post('/update', 'PostsController@update');
```

Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request) {
    $content = $request;

    return response($content);
}
```

AJAX:

```
data = {
    id: postID,
    title: $('[data-post-id='+postID+']').find('.blog_input').val(),
    content: 'testing testing'
};

$.post('/update', data, function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

For this I am constant getting an error of:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:
in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 655
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 629
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46....
```

I want to mention the input value on `title` is from a standalone input, it's not inside a full `<form>` if there's any clue that the problem might be this. How would I pass in or straighten out the CSRF token discrepancy?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are sending the CSRF Token on the request.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Alternatively you can turn this middleware off, but it's not advised really. See documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-introduction

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, using both @Buglinjo and @Paul's answers:

```
data = {
    _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    id: postID,
    title: $('[data-post-id='+postID+']').find('.blog_input').val(),
    content: 'testing testing'
};
```

Comment: I would recommend @paul's answer. Cos, following his method, every one of your ajax post call adds token by default instead of adding it manually for every ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use it to add a hidden input

```
 <input type="hidden" name="csrf" id="csrf" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

While accessing it via AJAX by

```
$('#csrf').val()
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add this in `data`:

```
data = {
    _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}', //this one
    id: postID,
    title: $('[data-post-id='+postID+']').find('.blog_input').val(),
    content: 'testing testing'
};
```

Comment: Tried this, it didn't work and gave me the same error.

Comment: I think it's only sending the literal `{{ csrf_token() }}` unpopulated